# How do I clear the text contents of a div in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm temporarily adding contents to a div,tempDiv, and adding that to a link which is appended to a div, #contentHere, that's displayed. I need to clear the contents of tempDiv so that the links aren't appended to each other, creating a string of urls that don't link to anywhere.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.getJSON("data.php", function(data){
     for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
         $("#tempDiv").append(data.justIn[i].dataLink+ '  ');
         $("#contentHere").append("<a href=\"#tempDiv\">Click to go to the div link</a>");
         //I need to clear the contents of tempDiv here
  }  
   });
});
```

Solutions to clearing the temporary contents of the div as I go?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `$("#tempDiv").empty()`.