# empty contents of a div tag based on user input using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I clear the text contents of a div in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039310/how-do-i-clear-the-text-contents-of-a-div-in-javascript)

Im actually making a web based terminal. I have a few ideas that I want to implement.

I have a textbox, upon typing in 'clear' into the texbox and pressing enter. The contents of the div should be cleared. The div tag here just shows the output, and i want to be able to clear it.

I have actually made the textbox, and it is accepting input such as -ls that shows the output on the browser.

Comment: This has [already been asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039310/how-do-i-clear-the-text-contents-of-a-div-in-javascript) many times before.

Comment: Yep, I wish people would search before asking/answering. So many duplicates on here now.

Comment: read the post before reaching to any conclusions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:

Suppose html is:

```
<input type="text" id="text" />
<div id="c">
    Contents here
</div>
```

The javascript would be:

```
$("#text").keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        if($(this).val() == "cls"){
           $("#c").empty();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) method:

```
$("#yourDivId").empty();
```

Or you can pass an empty string to the [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method:

```
$("#yourDivId").html("");
```

Comment: There`s also `.empty()` which is a tad shorter.

Comment: @slhck, true, forgot that one. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question. What about $("#terminal").empty()?

http://api.jquery.com/empty/

Comment: When the user types in "clear" in the textbox, the div contents should be removed after pressing enter.

Comment: so you're question is more about handling the user input than about clearing the div isn't it? You might want to change your title